# Processing Experimential Measurements in Python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I need to process data from a series of experiments. Each experiment has several sensor measurements in a 'csv' file, for example:

*experiment1.csv:*

```
time, sensor1, sensor2, sensor3
0, 1.3, 4.7, 2.9, 6.6
1, 2.8, 7.1, 4.2, 1.1
.
.
```

*experiment2.csv*

```
time, sensor1, sensor3, sensor6
0, 3.8, 7.1, 2.2, 1.1
1, 1.6, 4.1, 14.1, 3.7
.
.
```

I need to orginize the data so that I can easily compare measurements between trials. For example I might want to subtract the values measured by sensor 1 in experiment 1 from those measured by sensor 6 in experiment 2 and plot that difference as a function of time.

Right now I'm using pandas data frames to work with the data

```
exp1 = pd.read_csv('experiment1.csv')
exp2 = pd.read_csv('experiment2.csv')

diff = exp1['sensor1'] - exp2['sensor3']
plot(exp1['time'],diff)
```

This is cumbersome since I need to go in and manually create a new data frame when I want to add another experiment. Typically I might be working with data from 50 trials simultaneously and the method outlined does not scale well.

Ideally I'd like to have a script I can run in a directory with an arbitrary number of data files which would create a data frame for each file that I could then refer to by experiment designator and sensor number.

Is there some way I can modify the above code to create a data frame for each file in the directory without manually adding 'pd.read_csv' commands for every case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really are interested in is the `os` library -- specifically the `listdir` function.

But while you're at it, why not just combine all your measurements into one dataframe? You can add them as a column or as a level of a MultiIndex, whichever you prefer.

Here's the column approach:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
directory_contents = os.listdir(your_directory)
experiment_files = [fn for fn in directory_contents if '.csv' in fn]
df = pd.DataFrame()

for filename in experiment_files:
    experiment_df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    experiment_df['experiment_name'] = file_name
    df = pd.concat([df,experiment_df])
```

Comment: That does exactly what I need! Thanks!